# Pagination in Spring using @RestController, but without using Spring Data Rest Pageable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pagination, hibernate-query

I know using Spring Data Rest I can use the in-built functionality of Pagination Like this

```
Page<Product> findByCategoryId(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

However, I am in project I am using Spring mvc @RestController and want to achive the same functionality
I tried like this:-

```
Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Query<Product> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Product", Product.class);
theQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1) * pageSize); // This is 0 based
theQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<Product> dataList = theQuery.getResultList();  
return dataList;
```

It works but I don't get the **count** of **total number of records** in the table.
And for UI pagination I need that.

So do I have to hit 2 queries everytime first like above then 1 query to fetch record size. (Which can cause data sync problems if records are updated)

Or

Is there a better way to achieve this in ***SINGLE QUERY***

Comment: You cannot do this in a single query, you need 2. 1 for the count, the other for the page elements. Also this isn't Spring Data REST but rather a basic ffeature of Spring Data, so you don't need Spring Data Rest to be using pageable (you can use it with plain Spring Data JPA as well).

Comment: Ok Thanks @M. Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the total number of records then you must create a second query.

You could do that in one query with a subquery but then you cannot use Entities as return type.

Regarding data sync problems: If you run both queries in the same transaction there is no problem.

*Btw. why do you unwrap the Hiberante Session? There is no need for that in your example.*

Comment: "Btw. why do you unwrap the Hiberante Session? There is no need for that in your example." - Then how would I create a session object to create query?

Comment: entityManager.createQuery. EntityManager is the equivalent to Session in JPA. Session is Hiberante legacy

Comment: Returning to my original question, so how does Pageable internally works. Does it use single or multiple query to fetch total record size.

Comment: You are not using Pageable with Spring Data JPA. If you use JPA Repository you could return Page. And Spring Data JPA creates two queries

Comment: If my answer is helpful I would appreciate if you accept it.